# Assigning name to a org.springframework.core.io.Resource object

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am looking for a way to assign/set a filename to a `org.springframework.core.io.Resource` object. The object does not have a function available to do this. The `getFileName` method in my case returns a `null`.

I do not want to create a multipartfile from the Resource object since my Open API spec does not accept it.

Comment: Ther e is no `spring.io.Resource` object. Also a `Resource` is a generic construct in Spring and no you cannot assign a name. Because somethings (like inputstreams) don't have a name.

Comment: As stated `Resource` is generic and only specific ones have a name. And no you cannot use `setFilename` or the likes to set a name you can only do that during construction of the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved it like this

```
//Retrieved the object from S3
S3Object s3Object = amazonS3client.getObject(s3Config.getBucket(), key);
S3ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = s3Object.getObjectContent();
String fileName = s3Object.getObjectMetadata().getUserMetaDataOf("fileName");

//create a ByteArrayResource from the input stream and assigned the fileName
ByteArrayResource fileAsResource = new ByteArrayResource(IOUtils.toByteArray(objectInputStream)) {
                    @Override
                    public String getFilename() {
                        return fileName;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public long contentLength() {
                        return s3Object.getObjectMetadata().getContentLength();
                    }
                };
```

Answer (score 0):

header of get url is missing fileName after adding header like this will solve this issue

```
 s3Object.getObjectMetadata().setHeader("fileName","page-1-tables.csv");
```